# Hive Metastore Server ( CDH) started failed

Tags: mysql, hive, cloudera-manager

Recently I install CDH hadoop  (version 5.14.2)  but the HIVE Metastore Server   couldn't be started

it has one **`HiveServer2`** and  one   **`HIVE Metastore Server`**

when i started  it I have set  `datanucleus.autoCreateSchema`   `true`  to let hive create  its table  by itself ,

then the HiveServer2  started well  but HIVE Metastore Server failed   here is the logs

```
    ERROR   Datastore   
[main]: Error thrown executing CREATE TABLE `SERDE_PARAMS`
(
    `SERDE_ID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
    `PARAM_KEY` VARCHAR(256) BINARY NOT NULL,
    `PARAM_VALUE` VARCHAR(32672) BINARY NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `SERDE_PARAMS_PK` PRIMARY KEY (`SERDE_ID`,`PARAM_KEY`)
) ENGINE=INNODB : Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    ......

    ERROR   Schema  
[main]: An exception was thrown while adding/validating class(es) : Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    ......
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

    WARN    Query   
[main]: Query for candidates of org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MPartitionColumnStatistics and subclasses resulted in no possible candidates
An exception was thrown while adding/validating class(es) : Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    ......

org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: An exception was thrown while adding/validating class(es) : Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ......
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ......
    ... 36 more
Nested Throwables StackTrace:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    ......
```

I dont  know  how  to  soloved   `Column length too big for column 'PARAM_VALUE'` 
should  I  add some setting in mysql  (I use yum to install   version 5.6.40)

thanks  in advance .

Comment: could you please share my.cnf file of mysql db

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has a max row size limit of 65535 (minus storage overhead) Bytes. If in a charset(for eg: UTF-8) a character takes maximum 3 bytes, the maximum size of a varchar column can be 65535/3 = ~21845 assuming its the only column in the table. 
This is explained at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html

Changing the Charset to latin1 which has the maximum length of one, resolves this problem because in latin1 the column size can be maximum of 65535 approximately.

[Charset MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html)

Connect to Hive Metastore DB (MYSQL) and run 
ALTER DATABASE  CHARACTER SET latin1

[Change Charset for HiveMetastore DB](https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/HADOOP/blog/2014/06/18/2916362/Using+Hive+Metastore+on+Mac)

Comment: thanks for  your answer  , you have got the core message .  I will check your answer when I meet this problem again ,